# how to differ rational and irrational number in C++

Tags: c++

how to tell my float variable store an irrational number?

I'm a kind of newbie in C++
and I dont know many library function to be implemented

I want to make an exception for every calculation that end up being an irrational number

Comment: Using floating-point numbers, you can't really decide.

Comment: There is no such thing as "irrational" when dealing with floating-point variables as they don't have unlimited precision. You should store irrational numbers in another way if you need to.

Comment: @H2CO3 - you still here? I thought one more implicit int question and you are gone ;) You probably missed the one from yesterday.

Comment: @ddriver Aww, then I was lucky :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ doesn't have general arbitrary-precision rational numbers implemented. The available numbers are size-limited integers and floating point numbers.

A floating point number (in the common IEEE format) is however an integer multiplied by an exact power of two (positive or negative).

Even numbers like `0.1 = 1/10` are impossible to represent exactly because the denominator is not a power of two.

So the answer is simple :-) ... any number you will face with C++ is rational, more than that is an integer multiplied by a (possibly negative) power of two.

There are libraries implementing arbitrary precision integers and rational numbers, but they're not part of standard C++.

C++, by default, can only manage rational numbers. Moreover it's a very specific subset of the rationals where

1. The numerator is not too big in absolute value
2. The denominator is a power of two and it's not too big

When you write

```
double x = 1.0;
x = x / 10.0;
```

you get a result that is already outside of the capability of the C++ language because the denominator is not a power of two.
What the computer will do is storing into `x` a close approximation because `0.1` it's a number that cannot be stored exactly in IEEE double format.

Comment: I doubt it is truly arbitrary precision. I can keep asking infinitely for an approximate value of `PI` with one more decimal place than is currently calculated. They will run out of elementary particles in the Universe eventually to store it.

Comment: so it is all rational right? 
in my code
i want to calculate a calculation but it will be ended up as an irrational number
my question is, how to tell that the calculation i'm doing will ended up so?

Comment: @Sen You need to understand what is irrational number from the point of view of its definition. You cannot ever have a true value of `PI`, only approximation to a certain decimal place, albeit right now, I think, it's really big, like 5 trillion digits(?).

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are an approximation of the number. It is accurate as best that it can do with the limited amount of room to play in.

So the best bet is to limit the effect of both. It is called algebra. Also enables one to reduce round errors.